# Serializing a covariant override with MongoDB in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mapping, persistence

I have a base class similar to:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual object Id { get; set; }
}
```

And concrete classes override the property with more specific types, using C#'s covariant return type feature:

```
public class User : Entity
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
}
```

(This is a simplification of my situation, I'm not asking for a better model but only how to persist it)

Now my problem is that the Mongo BSON serializer thinks these are two separate properties, and it throws an exception because there are two properties that map to the same element.

How can I persist such a model (where properties are overridden with more specific types, assuming the types of the properties are serializable)?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the type of the property should be the same, otherwise it's 2 different properties, you may try to archive this behavior with custom [convention](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/conventions/), where you will need to ensure that all `Members` are registered correctly.

Comment: How do I choose between the members? I tried finding the property myself (with reflection) and mapping it manually and it still conflicts with the parent property

Comment: you should implement logic similar to what's done in `UnmapMember`: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/BsonClassMap.cs#L1118 but not exactly since in your case this condition `m => m.MemberInfo == memberInfo)` won't work correctly

Comment: note: I would look at `IPostProcessingConvention`

Comment: `How do I choose between the members?` - I would start with removing base class' members